# iOS Swift: Custom scroll animation for UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

When using the method `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` for UIScrollView, is it possible to use a custom animation? I would like to use a spring animation or a custom animation curve.

Answer (score 2):

```
if let itemFrame: CGRect = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath).frame {
    //UIView animate block here
    {
        collectionView.scrollToItemIndexPath(indexPath, yourScrollPosition, false/*animated parameter*/)
        /*or
        collectionView.setContentOffset(corresponding content offset to itemFrame)*/
    }
}
```

First access to frame of that particular item at indexPath and then scroll to that rect within your desired animation block. That should work.

Comment: That sort of works, although the view I'm animating from disappears immediately.